# Rails, creating an observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a field for Archived.

When a record is archived I want to send out a mailer notification. I thought about using an observer for this, problem is the observer tells me the record is archived after save but that doesn't mean it was just saved, it could have been saved as archied a while ago and this is just a title/desc update etc..

So what's the best way to handle this so I don't need to do the mailer etc in the controller? thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord gives you the magic for free.

`foo.archived_changed?`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty